# "Locking" image in place in div

Tags: html, css, positioning, image

I want to place an image at a certain place in a div, but it moves behind another div when resizing the window. I need it to be at the same place, at all times.

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">

<div id="gallerytext">
<p>This week's<br />heroes</p>
</div>

<div id="kranz">
<img src="images/kranz.png" alt="kranz" width="310px" />
</div>

<div id="pic1">
<img src="frontgallery/1.jpg" alt="gallery image 1" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="pic2">
<img src="frontgallery/2.jpg" alt="gallery image 2" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="pic3">
<img src="frontgallery/3.jpg" alt="gallery image 3" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="pic4">
<img src="frontgallery/4.jpg" alt="gallery image 4" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="pic5">
<img src="frontgallery/5.jpg" alt="gallery image 5" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="pic6">
<img src="frontgallery/6.jpg" alt="gallery image 6" width="25%" />
</div>

<div id="pic7">
<img src="frontgallery/7.jpg" alt="gallery image 7" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="pic8">
<img src="frontgallery/8.jpg" alt="gallery image 8" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="pic9">
<img src="frontgallery/9.jpg" alt="gallery image 9" width="20%" />
</div>

<div id="entergal">
<a href="index.html">Enter contest</a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#kranz img {
    position:absolute;
    left:42%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-13%;
    width:275px;
}
```

The images in the "gallery" are placed like this:

```
#pic2 img {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top:10%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10x #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
}
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with your code, or provide a working example so we can see the current results you have.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If the problem is that it ends up behind another image, have you tried  changing the z-index?

Comment: It doesn't go behind another image - it goes behind a div, placed above this one

Comment: Without actually seeing an example, I'd say that using floats and percentages for your margins may be what is causing your problem (along with z-index).  Have you tried position:fixed?  What is your result?

Comment: When using fixed, it moves when scrolling... I'll try to work out a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VDfN4/

Comment: Not sure I see what you are talking about.  I replaced all your images with placeholder images and tested it in chrome, ff, safari, and IE7, 8 and 9 and the 'kranz' sized image stayed on top of the other images no matter how I resized  http://jsfiddle.net/VDfN4/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the "kranz" is still moving when i resize the window. I want it to be at the same place, at all times

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly....

But try assigning

```
position:relative;
```

to all the divs which contain absolutely positioned images.

If an element has position:absolute; its position is calculated from the next relatively or absolutely positioned parent.

If positioned elements are not overlapping right, try z-index:

On top element

```
z-index:2
```

"Behind" Element

```
z-index:1;
```

Highest index is on top.

Comment: i dont see anything from my answer in your fiddle doesnt seem you tried

Comment: i see you have width specified in the image and in css, might wanna remove that. other than that pls clear up what you want it to look like as i can currently not understand at all.